# What is $\cos^2(x)$ in relation to $\sin(x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

How would you find $\cos^2(x)$ in terms of $\sin(x)$? Please explain clearly, I am a high school student.

Comment: Research a little more, please!.

Answer (score 4):

The key here is the *Pythagorean identity*, which states that $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$. You may have seen the Pythagorean identity in the form $a^2+b^2=c^2$ where $a,b$ are the lengths of the legs of a right triangle and $c$ is the length of the hypotenuse. The other form follows from this, as 
$$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=\frac{a^2}{c^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2}=\frac{a^2+b^2}{c^2}=\frac{c^2}{c^2}=1.$$
From this, it is easy to see that $\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$.

Answer (score 4):

Are you familiar with what is perhaps *the* most basic relationship between sine and cosine? For any $x$,
$$\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) = 1.$$

How you establish this depends on how you *define* sine and cosine. One way is to use a right triangle whose hypothenuse has length $1$, and has an angle of size $x$. Then the opposite side has length $\sin(x)$, because $\sin(x)$ is equal to the length of the opposite side divided by the length of the hypothenuse,
$$\sin(x) = \frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypothenuse}} = \frac{\text{opposite}}{1} = \text{opposite};$$
and in the same manner, the adjacent side has length $\cos(x)$, and so by the Pythagorean Theorem, we have that
$$\begin{align*}
(\text{opposite})^2 + (\text{adjacent})^2 &= (\text{hypothenuse})^2\\
\sin^2x + \cos^2x &= 1.
\end{align*}$$

Once you have that $\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) = 1$, solving for $\cos^2(x)$ will give you the expression you want.